# Is there any free *.diff file viewer?

Tags: windows-7, diff

Is there any free software that will run on Windows 7 to show syntax highlighting for `*.diff` files generated from comparing files? I don't want to *compare* files, just view the highlighted output from software which has already compared two files.

Comment: .diff files are plain text. Are there any features in *particular* that you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. my fried has tortoise SVN installed and that highlight the places of changes in code. I need a free app to open .diff file which can highlight changes like tortoise SVN diff viewer. I don't want to install tortoise SVN just to open .diff file, is there any other lightweight portable apps available

Comment: So then you want a diff viewer, and not just a .diff viewer?

Comment: yes, but tortoisesvn is actually comparing the files...  it's not just displaying a plain text diff file.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - no not a diff viewer i need `any-name.diff` viewer. what i want is available with tortoise svn but i'm looking for alternative

Comment: Tortoise SVN retrieves two versions of a file (i.e. two files) and computes their differences. No `.diff` file involved, since that only contains changes (+a bit of context), not the whole files.

Comment: @metalgearsolid, I edited your question based on the comments you posted. If you feel that I misinterpreted what you're looking for, feel free to further clarify your question.

Comment: You can google "syntax highlighter online" and find one that supports diff highlighting like this one: http://highlight.hohli.com/ or use most any popular code editor, or on GitHub you can paste your diff within `\`\`\`diff\n` and `\n\`\`\`` in a comment (where `\n` are newlines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As always: [VIM](http://www.vim.org/):

[image: viewing a diff file]

[image: viewing 2 files in diff mode]

Comment: Could you expand on this answer a bit? I see that it got accepted, but your three-word response isn't very helpful to future visitors of this question.

Comment: there are only 3 chars in 'vim' and that says it all as well :)

Comment: Actually, `vim` will do almost everything automatically :-). To compare two files, invoke `vimdiff file1 file2` on the command line. If you use the GUI version `gvim`, al least on Windows you can mark two files in Explorer, then context menu "compare in vim".

Comment: @sleske: hence the "as always" ...

Comment: vim is not always the answer, I have a 1200 lines long file and I will not use a tool like that

Comment: @akira, I'm still lost. How does one get from the first picture to the second?

Comment: @Shitesh `gvimdiff before.txt after.txt`

Comment: @akira How to do it if I have not before.txt and after.txt, but I have differences.diff ?

Comment: @David162795 then the only thing you can do is watch the .diff file.

Answer (score 10):

Notepad++ can open any text file and has a variety of syntax highlighting including diff files

Comment: I'd sure like a reference on that [cause there doesn't seem to be a Notepad++ patch viewing tool.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7053818/2642059)

Comment: Open the file in Notepad++ and select Language --> D --> Diff

Answer (score 7):

Free Options for diff viewing/editing/merging:

- [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/)
- [AJC Diff](http://www.ajcsoft.com/ProductsAJCDiff.php)
- [KDiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)
- [DiffMerge](http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)
- [Tortoise Merge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html)
- [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/) *
- [WinDiff](http://www.grigsoft.com/download-windiff.htm)
- [Diff Tool](http://www.guiffy.com/Diff-Tool.html) *

Wikipedia's recommendations: [Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools)

**Support Syntax Highlighting*

Comment: He doesn't need a file comparison tool, he needs a program that does syntax highlighting of diff files.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - Meld does syntax highlighting

Comment: It does file comparison. It does not do diff file syntax highlighting.

Comment: Meld can not open diff files!

Answer (score 1):

[FreeDiff](http://www.freediff.com) might meet your needs, but without know what exactly you are trying to do besides read it, its hard to say for sure.

Comment: I've tried this already and winmerge also . those are not I'm looking for. I don't want to compare 2 files. I just want to open .diff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do syntax highlighting, then its a case of: What is in the files, in order that it be highlighted? For example, C source files are parsed differently to XML files.

Perhaps (shudder) emacs would suit?

Comment: Almost *any* text editor better than Notepad will do it. But he may be looking for a dedicated diff file viewer.